# Possible to eliminate 1 of the loop? (writing header & writing data into CSV file)

Tags: swift, xcode

I think this is somehow inefficient. I need to do 2 checks to determine if the `newArray.isEmpty`. The first is to write the headers, and the second is to append the data into the CSV file.

The `newArray.isEmpty` is needed as the written output are different when its empty vs when it's not (note the `Target` header and the `\(target)` output)

Can this somehow be made into 1?

```
let newArray  = dataArray.dataPointsX.map(Int.init)

  do {
    if !newArray.isEmpty {
      try "Seconds, Target, TrainerPower, CyclePower, Delta(CyclePM - Trainer), PowerMatch Offset\n".appendToURL(fileURL: fileURL)
    } else {
      try "Seconds, TrainerPower, CyclePower, Delta(CyclePM - Trainer), PowerMatch Offset\n".appendToURL(fileURL: fileURL)
    }
  } catch {
    print("Could not write Headers to file")
  }
  
  for i in power.indices {
    
    let index = newArray.lastIndex(where: { $0 <= (i) }) ?? 0
    let target = !newArray.isEmpty ? Int(dataArray.dataPointsY[index]) : 0
    let deltaPower = powerAlt[i] - power[i]

    aveDeltaPower = (powerAlt.reduce(0, +) - power.reduce(0,+)) / power.count  // (sum CyclePower - Sum TrainerPower)/Total Count
    
    if !newArray.isEmpty {
      data = "\(i),\(target),\(power[i]),\(powerAlt[i]),\(deltaPower), \(aveDeltaPower)\n"
    } else {
      data = "\(i),\(power[i]),\(powerAlt[i]),\(deltaPower), \(aveDeltaPower)\n"
    }
    
    do {
      try data.appendToURL(fileURL: fileURL)
    }
    catch {
      print("Could not write data to file")
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could remember the `isEmpty` result in a `var` and check against it.

One thing to add. `isEmpty` in Swift is very fast with O(1) complexity (see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688398-isempty). That is because it is not counting elements, it compares `firstIndex != lastIndex`. 

It would be O(n) if you check with `newArray.count == 0`.

Comment: isn't checking ```isEmpty``` and checking as ```var``` the same. Maybe I should clarify that the check is cos the output data would be different. (notice the ```\(target)``` variable )

Comment: Using `newArray.isEmpty` several times is perfectly fine. Firstly, it's fast anyway, secondly the compiler can optimise several calls to constant expressions out of a block and move it on top of it. For example when array is a constant (yes), the compiler can move calls `array.isEmpty` to an expression `let isEmpty = array.isEmpty` at the beginning of the block. You should write your code in a way that is easy to read and understand. So, it's perfectly fine.